# OOPs in C. Default values for classes

Tags: c, oop, embedded

I'm learning to write C in OOPs to learn design patterns mentioned in the book "[Design Patterns for Embedded Systems in C](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Design_Patterns_for_Embedded_Systems_in.html?id=UnpIKZmodSAC&redir_esc=y&hl=en)" by Bruce Powel Douglass.

I would like to make a `__init__` method like in python where values are predefined and only if the user/dev wishes to change it he/she needs to.

**What have I done**
I define an `instance of a struct` with default values and `extern` it to the application/middleware. So if the user needs two instances he needs to go create another instance with the default values.

```
/* Sensor */
typedef struct sensor sensor;
struct sensor{
    uint8_t parameter1;
    uint8_t parameter2;
    uint8_t parameter3;
    uint8_t parameter4;
    void (*initilize)(uint8_t parameter1, uint8_t parameter2, 
            uint8_t, parameter3, uint8_t parameter4);
    void (*read)(uint8_t * parameter1, uint16_t parameter2);
    void (*write)(uint16_t *parameter2);
};

void sensor_init(sensor *this, uint8_t parameter1, uint8_t parameter2, 
            uint8_t, parameter3, uint8_t parameter4);
void sensor_read(sensor *this, uint8_t * parameter1, uint16_t parameter2);
void sensor_write(sensor *this, uint16_t *parameter2);
```

And then every time the user needs to make a new object me must:

```
sensor Sensor1 = {
    .parameter1 = 1, .parameter2 = 2, .parameter3 = 3, .parameter4 = 4,
    .initilize = sensor_init, .read = sensor_read, .write = sensor_write
};
```

Is there a better way to initialize? Where the user/dev can call

```
sensor Sensor;
Sensor.init();
```

or

```
Sensor.Init(parameter1 = 22);
```

Something like polymorphism.

Comment: There's one thing you forget about your "member functions": Passing the object itself! The compiler will not do it automatically, there's no `this` variable in the functions. You explicitly have to pass the object to the functions, by modifying them to take a *pointer* to the "object".

Comment: Ah, yes. Like `void write(sensor this, uint26_t param2)`? Yes this is needed if I wish to `self` address the object inside these functions. Good idea, I can have my buffer pointer and other stuff inside the object too. Everything will be so organized. Sorry, new to OOPs

Comment: Sidenote: That's a potentially dangerous thing, expecially in embedded systems. And many coding standards disallow function pointers in RAM or at least combined with the data.

Comment: @Olaf I've heard the dangers that function pointers can bring but the author "Bruce Powel Douglass" doesn't (or hasn't, I'm still reading the book) addressed this in the book. How different is an embedded system to a PC when it has to handle function pointers? Also, how do you build modular, reusable code?

Comment: @ClamentJohn: Would you like to be in your car/train/plane at 200+km/h if e.g. by EMI the pointer to the breeak function flips a bit?? I don't know the author, nor the book, but in general reading a book does not off-load one from thinking.

Comment: @Olaf Woah can that seriously happen?! But your argument can apply to pure C too. The program counter could go to the wrong function (or no function at all) by a flip in bits.

Comment: @ClamentJohn: This is certainly not the place to discuss good software design practice or principles of functional safety. So this is my last contribution: do you really consider anything which might go wrong with a game or document (which will show up on next load, btw.) to be as problematic as e.g. cars or medical devices? Btw: for all these OOP in C is common practice. Just not the way it seems to be propagated by this book. I leave it to you judge its quality in this light.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174852/discussion-between-clament-john-and-olaf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a *factory* function which creates and sets up your "object" from the "class". This is a very common way to do it.

Example

```
sensor sensor_create()
{
    return (sensor){
        .parameter1 = 1, .parameter2 = 2, .parameter3 = 3, .parameter4 = 4,
       .initilize = sensor_init, .read = sensor_read, .write = sensor_write
    };
};

// ...

sensor Sensor1 = sensor_create();
```

Comment: Great, thank you! How can I change the parameter values `sensor Sensor1 = sensor_create(parameter1 = 22)` on run time? Eg, if two sensors are to have different settings

Comment: It can be abbreviated to: `sensor sensor_create(){return (sensor){1, 2, 3, 4, sensor_init, sensor_read, sensor_write};}` because all members are initialized so the membe designators are not needed (and my old C compiler likes it better)

Comment: @ClamentJohn Unfortunately you then have to provide arguments for *all* member variables. You can create different factory functions taking different sets of parameters for different and common combinations.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks that was really helpful. So I use the factory function (which is again part of design pattern I hope to learn) to create the instance and before 'init', I have to update the 'params'. Cool

Comment: @PaulOgilvie A compiler which accepts compound literals but not designators? That's a weird combination... :)

Comment: No, you must update the instance _after_ the factory function as that overwrites all membes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, indeed, VC2008 doesn't accept any of these forms.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Ah, well MSVC have always been the odd one out, especially the older versions... :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you explain why there has to be a parenthesis around `return (sensor)...` ?

Comment: @pbn My function is returning a [*compound literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Answer (score 1):

You can add your structure as parameter of your function pointer initialize:

`void (*initilize)(uint8_t parameter1, uint8_t parameter2, uint8_t, parameter3, uint8_t parameter4, struct class1_t *this);`

Then you can `this->parameter1 = parameter1;` in the initialize function